# Does the stackexchange mobile app use HTTPS?

Tags: encryption, tls, apple

I am curious whether the stackexchange mobile app (specifically on the Apple app store) uses HTTPS protocols, does it?

Is this the same with other apps that access the stackexchange network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stack Exchange network is only accessible over HTTPS. If you try to access it over HTTP, you'll just get a redirect:

```
% curl --include http://stackoverflow.com/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/
[…]
```

Additionally, Apple has measures in place to incentivize apps to use HTTPS. Apps are required to [explicitly declare which servers they will use HTTP to communicate with](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33), and [Apple may reject apps which are not using HTTPS appropriately](http://blog.safedk.com/technology/ios-ats-apple-store-policy-rejected/).

Comment: Your test isn't quite suitable here. Every app accessing the Stack Exchange sites uses the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). You should compare the results of API calls made over [HTTP](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/204656/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=security) and [HTTPS](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/204656/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=security). The plain HTTP API call returns an empty set of items: `{"items":[],"has_more":false,"quota_max":300,"quota_remaining":280}`